# Why can I not type into the input fields using Formik and Yup?

Tags: input, next.js, formik, yup

When I am trying to type into the input fields there are no letters appearing. I actually have a login page using similar code working fine, so I have no clue right now why it is not working on this one. I thought it might have something to do with the way I defined the initialValues, because they are nested, but I already tried to write them not nested and it did not work.

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
import { FormikValues, useFormik, validateYupSchema } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Register: NextPage = () => {

  const router = useRouter()
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if (session) {
    router.push('/')
  }

  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  const handleRegister = async ({
    userInfo: {
      email,
      password
    },

    companyInfo: {
      companyName,
      gender,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      street,
      houseNumber,
      postcode,
      city,
      country,
      countryCode,
      callNumber,
      emailAddress,
      website,
      socials
    } }: FormikValues) => {

    const userInfo: Prisma.UserCreateInput = {
      email,
      hashedPassword: password //Not hashed yet!
    }

    const companyInfo: Prisma.CompanyCreateInput = {
      name: companyName,
      gender,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      street,
      houseNumber,
      postcode,
      city,
      country,
      countryCode,
      callNumber,
      emailAddress,
      website,
      socials,
      companyUser: {
        connect: { id: '' }
      }
    }

    const registerData: FormikValues = {
      userInfo,
      companyInfo
    }

    const registerDataJSON = JSON.stringify(registerData)

    const endpoint: RequestInfo = '/api/register/register'
    const options: RequestInit = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: registerDataJSON
    }

    try {
      const response: Response = await fetch(endpoint, options)

      const url = response.headers.get('Location')

      if (url) {
        window.location.href = url
      }
    } catch {
      setError('Register failed')
    } finally {
      formik.setSubmitting(false)
    }
  }

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      userInfo: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },

      companyInfo: {
        companyName: '',
        gender: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        street: '',
        houseNumber: '',
        postcode: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
        countryCode: '',
        callNumber: '',
        emailAddress: '',
        website: '',
        socials: ''
      }
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
      userInfo: Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .required('email address is required')
          .email('email address must be valid')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Email Address cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        password: Yup.string()
          .required('Password address is required')
          .min(8, 'Password must be at least 8 characters long')
          .max(20, 'Password cannot be longer than 20 characters')
          .matches(
            /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])/,
            'Password must contain at least one number as well as one uppercase, lowercase and special character'
          )
          .trim('Password cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
          .matches(
            /^(?!.* )/,
            'Password cannot contain whitespaces'
          )
      }),
      companyInfo: Yup.object().shape({
        companyName: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(50, 'Company Name cannot be longer than 50 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Company Name cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        gender: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(20, 'Gender cannot be longer than 20 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Gender cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        firstName: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(50, 'First Name cannot be longer than 50 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('First Name cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        lastName: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(50, 'Last Name cannot be longer than 50 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Last Name cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        street: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(50, 'Street cannot be longer than 50 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Street cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        houseNumber: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(10, 'House Number cannot be longer than 10 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Hpuse Number cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        postcode: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(50, 'Postcode cannot be longer than 50 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Postcode cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        city: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(58, 'City cannot be longer than 58 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('City cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        country: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(56, 'Country cannot be longer than 56 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Country cannot include leading and trailing spaces'),
        countryCode: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(10, 'Country Code cannot be longer than 10 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Country Code cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
          .matches(
            /^(?!.* )/,
            'Country Code cannot contain whitespaces'
          ),
        callNumber: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .min(1, 'Call Number must be bigger than 0')
          .max(20, 'Call Number cannot be longer than 20 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Country Code cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
          .matches(
            /^(?!.* )/,
            'Call Number cannot contain whitespaces'
          ),
        emailAddress: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .email('Email Address must be valid')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Email Address cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
          .matches(
            /^(?!.* )/,
            'Email Address cannot contain whitespaces'
          ),
        website: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .url('Website must be a URL')
          .max(100, 'Website cannot be longer than 100 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Website cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
          .matches(
            /^(?!.* )/,
            'Website cannot contain whitespaces'
          ),
        socials: Yup.string()
          .strict(true)
          .required()
          .max(100, 'Socials cannot be longer than 100 characters')
          .transform((value) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
          .trim('Socials cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
      })
    }),
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      handleRegister(values)
    }
  })

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} noValidate>
      <h2>User Information</h2>

      <label>
        Email Address<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='email'
          type='email'
          value={formik.values.userInfo.email}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.userInfo?.email && formik.errors.userInfo?.email && <p>{formik.errors.userInfo.email}</p>}

      <label>
        Password<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='password'
          type='password'
          value={formik.values.userInfo.password}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.userInfo?.password && formik.errors.userInfo?.password && <p>{formik.errors.userInfo.password}</p>}

      <h2>Company Information</h2>

      <label>
        Company Name<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='companyName'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.companyName}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.companyName && formik.errors.companyInfo?.companyName && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.companyName}</p>}

      <label>
        Gender<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='gender'
          type='text'
          list='genders'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.gender}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
        <datalist id='genders'>
          <option>Female</option>
          <option>Male</option>
        </datalist>
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.gender && formik.errors.companyInfo?.gender && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.gender}</p>}

      <label>
        First Name<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='firstName'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.firstName}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.firstName && formik.errors.companyInfo?.firstName && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.firstName}</p>}

      <label>
        Last Name<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='lastName'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.lastName}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.lastName && formik.errors.companyInfo?.lastName && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.lastName}</p>}

      <label>
        Street<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='street'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.street}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.street && formik.errors.companyInfo?.street && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.street}</p>}

      <label>
        House Number<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='houseNumber'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.houseNumber}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.houseNumber && formik.errors.companyInfo?.houseNumber && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.houseNumber}</p>}

      <label>
        Postcode<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='postcode'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.postcode}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.postcode && formik.errors.companyInfo?.postcode && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.postcode}</p>}

      <label>
        City<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='city'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.city}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.city && formik.errors.companyInfo?.city && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.city}</p>}

      <label>
        Country<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='country'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.country}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.country && formik.errors.companyInfo?.country && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.country}</p>}

      <label>
        Country Code<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='countryCode'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.countryCode}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.countryCode && formik.errors.companyInfo?.countryCode && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.countryCode}</p>}

      <label>
        Call Number<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='callNumber'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.callNumber}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.callNumber && formik.errors.companyInfo?.callNumber && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.callNumber}</p>}

      <label>
        Email Address<span>*</span>
        <input
          name='emailAddress'
          type='email'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.emailAddress}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.emailAddress && formik.errors.companyInfo?.emailAddress && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.emailAddress}</p>}

      <label>
        Website
        <input
          name='website'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.website}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.website && formik.errors.companyInfo?.website && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.website}</p>}

      <label>
        Socials
        <input
          name='socials'
          type='text'
          value={formik.values.companyInfo.socials}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
      </label>
      {formik.touched.companyInfo?.socials && formik.errors.companyInfo?.socials && <p>{formik.errors.companyInfo.socials}</p>}

      <button type='submit' disabled={formik.isSubmitting}>Login</button>
      {formik.isSubmitting && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {!formik.isSubmitting && error && <div>{error}</div>}
    </form>
  )
}

export default Register
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have nested initialValues, the name of the input must represent the property of the corresponding object. Regarding your example you have to change the current name of the input ('email') to 'userInfo.email' as showcased below:

```
<input
  name="userInfo.email"
  type="email"
  value={formik.values.userInfo.email}
  onChange={formik.handleChange}
  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
/>
```